What exactly triggers the following SSHD warning, suspected IP change?
I have connected via SSH to the server before (using name, not IP).
What exactly triggers the following SSHD message:

Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address
'[xx.xx.xx.xx]:23' to the list of known hosts.

This is a managed server - could it mean that the IP changed, while the hostkey remains the same?

did you have to take any action to accept the new hostkey, or did it just automatically add it to known_hosts and display the warning? is you client configured to point to TCP\23?

Yes - no manual action, key was added to known_hosts automatically (script run in the night). Yes, client pointed to TCP/23.

in that case Giancomo1968's answer seems probable. if the key had changed due to perhaps a server replacement or a new port redirect, you would have been required to explicitly accept the new key.


“What exactly triggers the following SSHD message:”

That would most likely be a server upgrade of the SSHD (SSH Daemon) that switched the host key from RSA encoding to ECDSA encoding.
If you do a casual search for ECDSA nowadays you will see you are not the only one who has had this issue because ECDSA is begin favored over RSA due to known vulnerabilities with RSA as explained here in this Information Security SE site.
Of course you could force/change the sever host key to be RSA again, but it is not recommended and it most likely would have to be a 100% new RSA key which would ask for revalidation of the host key again.
Also, when you say this:

“I have connected via SSH to the server before (using name, not IP).”

Each way you connect via SSH — via hostname or IP address — adds a new entry to the ~/.ssh/known_hosts file. So if you previously connected to the server via hostname and then changed to connecting it via IP address, it would ask/state that again.

I did not change to using IP address instead of hostname. But a change from RSA to ECDSA makes sense to me. Gonna ask the hosting company.
